# Latest Windows 10 update has enforced adaptive brightness

Tags: windows-10, intel-graphics, brightness, windows-10-v1709

I have a Samsung XE700T1C tablet/laptop, which before the latest 1709 update was behaving as intended when attempting to amend the brightness controls.

Naturally, I've disabled adaptive brightness everywhere I could think of, however the result is still the same. I am given the option to choose a brightness percentage, but no matter what I choose it remains adaptive. This happens on both battery and whilst plugged in, and I don't have any BIOS settings related to this.

Settings I have checked as per screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Graphics device is an Intel HD 4000, driver version 10.18.10.4885. I'm going to try and revert the driver to stock in case this helps. **EDIT:** I have tried driver 10.18.10.4242 as supplied by Samsung with no positive benefit.

Answer (score 2):

I'm on a desktop now so I can't verify the accuracy of the proposed solutions but some people report to have had success with either removing a scheduled task or disabling a specific service.

**Solution 1**

Go to start > search for "task scheduler" and browse to Task Scheduler Library > Microsoft > Windows > Display > Brightness and disable the task called "Brightness Reset".

**Solution 2**

Go to start > search for "Services" and disable the Sensor Service. This might have undesired side effects though as it also reads the rotation sensor of tablets.

Comment: Well, solution 2 certainly improves matters, although the first ~30% of the brightness bar has no effect on actual brightness. I'm a little concerned about any side effects, but it'll certainly do the trick until I can find a better method (and establish what the side effects are), thank you. Note that my rotation sensor is still working fine, as well as GPS, so I'm not sure what else this service actually monitors yet!